# multi-tenancy with sqlalchemy - can't seem change query on event.listen

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to add a company_id filter to all queries to the database with sqlalchemy.

I've got the event firing with the below.

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def my_load_listener(target, context):
    print("on load!")

event.listen(Settings, 'load', my_load_listener)
```

Looks like I can get a select object with `context.query` but I've used the below to try and add a filter but cant get it to work.

```
context.query = context.query.where(Settings.id == 2)
```

Is it possible to intercept a models query / insert and amend it on the fly?

Ideally it would be achievable on a global scope so I don't have to add events for all models.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/examples/extending_query/filter_public.py) example from SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I have not, thank you I will take a look.